# Поиск элемента в базе данных SQLite3 Python

Tags: python, sqlite3

У меня есть база данных:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INT,
    name TEXT,
    cash INT,
    mes INT
    )""")
```

В функции, я получаю имя пользователя и на выходе имею `имя пользователя с тегом`, например: `coder#1234` с типом данных `string`.
Как я могу узнать колонку `id`, если `имя пользователя с тегом` это колонка `name`?

Я пробовал `cursor.execute(f'SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = {str(member)}')`, но это не рабочий код, выдает ошибку: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "#5978": syntax error`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не ответ, но в комментарий помещать неудобно:

SQLite3  не знаю, как и `cursor.execute` :-)

Советую как шаг 1 (тест "в лоб"):

`SELECT id FROM users WHERE name=coder#1234`
или
`SELECT id FROM users WHERE name='coder#1234'`

Comment: Да, все нормально сработало.

Comment: Благодарю, сам почему-то не додумался. Оказывается надо было после name= , поставить ковычки, чтобы присвоить тип текста и все.

Comment: Это плохой совет из-за проблем с [внедрением sql-кода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). Нужно использовать связываемые переменные https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-placeholders